Why does installing crewai fail on windows on python 3.12 and 3.13 but works on 3.11?
I get consistent error installing crewAI package in a Virtual env on python3.12 and 3.13 with an error while compiling regex and tiktoken. I had installed visual c++ build tools and Rust compiler separately which were pointed out as dependencies in other threads but something is broken in the package build. It however worked with python 3.11 which seems strange. I am on pip 24. With 3.11 it was pip 22.
Error I get with newer python version:
regex_3\_regex.c(1267): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex
  Building wheel for tiktoken (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for tiktoken (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1


I can confirm - CrewAI installation is clean on Python 3.11 but seems broken with 3.12 and 3.13. Dont understand the root cause , likely some hard dependencies because i get syntactical errors in the compilation of regex.c code but it was smooth in 3.11.
